# Adding filtered row names as labels in geom_point using geom_text (error on length of the dataset)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, geom-text, geom-point

I have a dataset and I want to add specific labels (row names in this case) to my ggplot graph. However, when I use filter, an error regarding length of the data frame shows on the console.
I would appreciate if anyone could help me to resolve the issue.

```
require("ggrepel")
require("tidyerse")

x <- sample(x = 1:20, size = 30, replace = T)
y <- sample(x = 1:20, size = 30, replace = T)
df <- data.frame(x,y)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label = rownames(df)))

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text_repel(data = df %>% filter(x>10), 
                    aes(label = rownames(df)))
```

Error in `check_aesthetics()`:
! Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (14): label

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `df` for rownames, then it would still return all rownames. So, you need to also add you filter statement inside of `rownames()` (i.e., `aes(label = rownames(df %>% filter(x > 10)))`).

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text_repel(data = df %>% filter(x > 10),
                  aes(label = rownames(df %>% filter(x > 10))))
```

[image]

Comment: It seems I ended up answering the same as you and a minute later, should I delete my answer?

Comment: @shafee Yeah, that's usually what I do, if end up posting the same answer after someone else. I've had it happen where I was only a few seconds.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way could be:

Here we define the labels beforehand by adding a column `my_label` conditional on x> 10.
No need to subset within ggplot:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(group_id = x > 10) %>% 
  mutate(my_label = ifelse(group_id == TRUE, as.character(row_number()), "")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=y))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_text_repel(aes(label=my_label))
```

[image]